# reading image as arraybuffer using uint8 and uint16 array

Tags: javascript, filereader, fileapi, unsigned-integer

Here is a piece of code to check the uploaded image mime type by checking for desired ***magic number***(i still don't understand them clearly yet). when i supply the blob file to uint8Array it works, the array populates. But if i use uint16array it gives an error. What might be the reason for this error. It says invalid argument.

I have two question on this topic.

***1. why i can't i use uint16array instead uint8array ?***

***2. i read wikipedia. But it contains lots of technical stuff. Can you shed some light on 'magic number' so that i can understand what it really is(in a nutshell)***

[image]

```
var upload=document.getElementById('upload');
upload.addEventListener('change',function(e){



    if(window.File && window.FileReader &&  window.FileList){

                    var file=e.target.files[0];
                    console.log(file.type);

                    var fileReader=new FileReader();

                    fileReader.onload= function(e){
                             var arr = (new Uint8Array(e.target.result));

                             console.log(arr);
                             var arr2=(new Uint16Array(e.target.result));
                             console.log(arr2);

                    };
             fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
             }else{
                 alert('file api not compatible with your browser');
             }  

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't use an Uint16Array here because the file has an odd number of bytes. By definitive, an Uint16Array needs an even number of bytes (a multiple of 2).

   Also, I'm not quite sure what purpose it would serve. An Unit16Array reads the data in platform byte order, which will lead to different results depending on the platform. And you can definitely check a magic number with bytes.
2. A magic number is simply a sequence of bytes at a given location (often at the very start of the file) which allows one to recognise the file type. Of course, the presence of the magic number is not enough to make the file a valid file for the recognised format, but its absence definitely rules out the file being of the required type (for file types which include a magic number, which is not necessarily the case for all of them).

Comment: thanks for the reply. i didn't find anything which claim that uint16 require odd number of bytes.can you provide any source where i can read it by myself

Comment: @AL-zami No, it doesn't require an odd number of bytes, quite the opposite. How could it handle an odd number of bytes? What would do with the last one? I'm not sure it's specifically documented anywhere, but you can do the test: `console.log(new Uint16Array(new ArrayBuffer(16)));` (works) `console.log(new Uint16Array(new ArrayBuffer(17)));` (doesn't)